# What is USB error -62?

Tags: usb, kernel, logging

When I plug a USB mouse into a computer, the following error appears in the logs:

```
Mar 24 21:43:03 homer kernel: [ 2674.768039] usb 2-9: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci_hcd
Mar 24 21:43:03 homer kernel: [ 2674.952050] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/64, error -62
Mar 24 21:43:03 homer kernel: [ 2675.236034] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/64, error -62
Mar 24 21:43:03 homer kernel: [ 2675.516035] usb 2-9: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci_hcd
Mar 24 21:43:04 homer kernel: [ 2675.696042] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/64, error -62
Mar 24 21:43:04 homer kernel: [ 2675.980047] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/64, error -62
Mar 24 21:43:04 homer kernel: [ 2676.260043] usb 2-9: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci_hcd
Mar 24 21:43:05 homer kernel: [ 2676.668034] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 5, error -62
Mar 24 21:43:05 homer kernel: [ 2676.764039] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 9
Mar 24 21:43:14 homer kernel: [ 2685.852045] usb 2-9: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ohci_hcd
Mar 24 21:43:14 homer kernel: [ 2686.036033] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/64, error -62
Mar 24 21:43:14 homer kernel: [ 2686.324032] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/64, error -62
Mar 24 21:43:14 homer kernel: [ 2686.608043] usb 2-9: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ohci_hcd
Mar 24 21:43:15 homer kernel: [ 2686.788043] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/64, error -62
Mar 24 21:43:15 homer kernel: [ 2687.076043] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/64, error -62
```

I've seen similar questions on askubuntu with similar error messages, but never with error -62. What does this error code mean? Is there a table of all error codes and their meaning? I google around but could not find it.

Comment: You could try taking a look [here](https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error).

Comment: @Terrance, your link is spot on. It was a hardware failure (see my comment below).

Comment: Glad that link helped.  =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed a list of the kernel error codes and depending on how your system is set up you should find the codes in `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h`. To find error 62 simply run:

```
$ grep '62' /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h
#define ETIME       62  /* Timer expired */
```

And to browse the entire list of over 100  error codes try:

```
cat /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h | less
```

This should give you a starting point in finding the reason for your USB device failure. I suspect that the hardware (USB device) is faulty in terms of connection and the kernel simply times out in its attempt to run the device = Error 62.

Comment: In the end it was a hardware failure. I turned off the PC, completely shut off the power supply, and let it rest 10 minutes. After that, it never turned on anymore.