# Bluetooth on GC-WBAX1200 Bluetooth and WIFI card not working on Ubuntu 22.04 (Dualboot System with Windows)

Tags: drivers, 22.04, bluetooth

I have a Gigabyte GC-WBAX1200 WIFI and Bluetooth PCIE-Card in my PC and it has worked fine on Windows before installing Ubuntu 20.04. But after installing Ubuntu it has lost its Bluetooth capability both on Windows and Ubuntu, while WIFI works just fine on both systems.

Trying to fix that I have upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04 LTS and tried installing drivers and more but nothing works and no bluetooth dongles are detected.

`lspci` shows
`06:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0608` which presumably is the card.

`systemctl status bluetooth`:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Mär 02 21:42:22 a1111-Z390-AORUS-PRO systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Mär 02 21:51:32 a1111-Z390-AORUS-PRO systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Mär 02 21:54:39 a1111-Z390-AORUS-PRO systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

Edit:

In dmesg I can see that the firmware seems to be loaded correctly:

```
[   67.244407] mt7921e 0000:06:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
[   67.340075] mt7921e 0000:06:00.0: HW/SW Version: 0x8a108a10, Build Time: 20231109190918a
[   67.353170] mt7921e 0000:06:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____010000, Build Time: 20231109190959
[   67.387670] mt7921e 0000:06:00.0: Firmware init done
[   68.971016] mt7921e 0000:06:00.0 wlp6s0: renamed from wlan0
```

But if I understand the logs correctly it seems like the WIFI and Bluetooth parts are split into two different USB devices and one loads correctly (probably WIFI) while the 1-11 has some errors:

```
a1111@a1111-Z390-AORUS-PRO:~$ sudo dmesg | grep 608
[    0.031447] Inode-cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes, linear)
[    0.758515] pci 0000:06:00.0: [14c3:0608] type 00 class 0x028000
[    2.137949] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=85.36
[   44.805924] usb 1-13: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=85.36
a1111@a1111-Z390-AORUS-PRO:~$ sudo dmesg | grep 1-11
[    1.988439] usb 1-11: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.137949] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=85.36
[    2.137960] usb 1-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.137966] usb 1-11: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    2.139178] hub 1-11:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.139518] hub 1-11:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    2.496436] usb 1-11.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    7.812543] usb 1-11.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   23.428547] usb 1-11.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   23.616447] usb 1-11.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   28.804547] usb 1-11.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   44.420539] usb 1-11.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   44.528884] usb 1-11-port2: attempt power cycle
[   45.136462] usb 1-11.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[   55.812453] usb 1-11.2: device not accepting address 8, error -62
[   55.892451] usb 1-11.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[   66.564459] usb 1-11.2: device not accepting address 9, error -62
[   66.564907] usb 1-11-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

lspci and lsubs:

```
a1111@a1111-Z390-AORUS-PRO:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th/9th Gen Core 8-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake S] (rev 0d)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 0d)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z390 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V (rev 10)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Upstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev 11)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Downstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev 11)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 747e (rev c8)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device ab30
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5017 (rev 01)
06:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0608
07:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. A2000 NVMe SSD (rev 03)
a1111@a1111-Z390-AORUS-PRO:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1038:2202 SteelSeries ApS Arctis Nova 7
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 048d:8297 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. IT8297 RGB LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: The "Condition check" is on Bluetooth being detected by the kernel. Do you see any error messages related to Bluetooth in `dmesg`?

Comment: Not directly but I may have found the root of my problem being the card being split into two USB-devices and the bluetooth one not being detected properly. Edited my question to include more infos

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1380495/1004020 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1487220/1004020 . Does it work on a 23.10 LiveCD? If not, please [edit] with the full `lspci` and `lsusb`

Comment: Same issues while trying Ubuntu 23.10 off an USB-Stick. Added lspci and lsusb

Comment: There might be a loose wire: https://askubuntu.com/q/749840/1004020 . Also see if `sudo modprobe btmtk` causes the device to show up

Comment: The device still doesn´t show up and with the meaning of the error codes it may just be a hardware issue? But I would find that rather weird, since WIFI is still working

Comment: Can you remove the Genesys Logic Hub and boot again, see if the results from `lsusb` changed?

Comment: I have removed every USB-Device from my PC and even the WIFI/Bluetooth card but it Genesys Logic Hub is still showing. So I don´t really know what device it is and it may be the Hub on my motherboard. I have a Gigabyte Z390 Aorus Pro

Comment: A BIOS reset might get the device working again

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth works now, but I am not entirely sure what has fixed is, but I can list my last steps that may have fixed it:

- Upgraded the kernel to 5.19
- Installed bluetooth5.19
- Added the lines as described in this post [No wifi adapter found on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380400/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts/1380495#1380495)
- Installed modprobe btmtk (I believe its a part of Kernel 5.19
- Installed drivers as described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1476253/1772573

I believe the biggest factor is the update to Kernel version 5.19 and thus being able to use current firmware

Comment: Kernel 5.19 has been unsupported for a year, better switch to 6.5